# Why can't I subtract one date period from the next and convert to an integer?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to determine whether a difference between two months is an even or odd number of months.

I used the command:

```
import pandas as pd
(pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01').to_period('M')) % 2
```

This seems to work in python 3.6.7, but in another python 3.7.3 environment I get the error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> (pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01').to_period('M')) % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'MonthEnd' and 'int'
```

I'm trying to work out what package would make the difference here, or if there is another way to do what I want that would work in both versions?

I took a look at my installed packages and there are a few version differences but I have no idea which would make the difference.

The environment that does not work has python 3.7.3, pandas 0.24.2, and numpy-base 1.16.2. The environment that works has python 3.6.7, pandas 0.22.0, but does not have any version of numpy-base. Both have python-dateutil 2.8.0 and numpy 1.16.2.

Comment: It seems that in 3.7.3 the return type is `pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd` as opposed to int earlier.

Comment: It's probably about the pandas version

Comment: Returns int on 3.7.1

Comment: @run-out The issue is pandas version not python version, 0.24.2 gives error, but my version (0.19.2) (that's very old), works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is [Period Subtraction](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#period-subtraction) in pandas 0.24+:

> Subtraction of a Period from another Period will give a DateOffset. instead of an integer (GH21314)

Solution is attribut `.n`:

```
a = (pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').to_period('m') - pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01').to_period('m'))

print (a)
<5 * MonthEnds>

print (a.n)
5

print (a.n % 2)
1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because in pandas 0.24.2, it returns:

```
<5 * MonthEnds>
```

Which isn't a `int`eger, instead a `MonthEnd` object, so you would need to do `.n`, which gives you the actual number of `5`:

```
print((pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').to_period('M') - pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01').to_period('M')).n % 2)
```

Which outputs:

```
1
```