# Python Pandas Period Date difference is in * MonthEnds>, how to convert it into INT value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find Period date difference. Per Pandas 0.24+ : Subtraction of a Period from another Period will give a DateOffset. instead of an integer (GH21314). But how to get INT results. I have look into similar query: [Why can't I subtract one date period from the next and convert to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016233/why-cant-i-subtract-one-date-period-from-the-next-and-convert-to-an-integer)
It says adding ".n" will give results, but that didn't work for me.

I also tried converting both into INT using .astype(int), but getting error: 'Period' object has no attribute 'astype'. I must be missing something, not sure what!

I am using Pandas Version: '1.0.1'.

DDL to generate Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

date_start = pd.Period('10/2018',freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                  'date_end': ['2017-01', '2018-08', '2019-04','2018-06', 
                               '2018-12', '2018-10']})
df['date_end'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y-%m'),
                                freq='M')

df['diff'] = date_start - df['date_end']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the individual `Period[M]` objects, not the series:

```
df['diff'].n
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'n'

df['diff'].apply(lambda x: x.n)

0    21
1     2
2    -6
3     4
4    -2
5     0
```

Comment: Above solution isn't working, if any of date_end has missing value. Getting error: AttributeError: 'NatType' object has no attribute 'n'.